# jQuery - Display Loading Image only once on keyup

Tags: jquery

I have a `keyup` function to search for a data on a table. I want to make the loading image appear only **once**. For example, if user type `"one"`, the image will appear only one time until the result appear.

I'm able to show the image upon `keyup` function but it will appear base on what user type. For example, if user type `"one"`, the image will appear 3 times. Below are the example of my codes,

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){
    var search = $("#search").val();
    $("#loading").fadeIn(500);
    $.post('search_pr.php',
    {
        search : search
    })
    .done(function(data){
        $("#loading").fadeOut(500);
        $("#body").html(data);
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a **flag** for this,

```js
$(function(){
var load_img = false;
$("#search").keyup(function(){
   var search = $("#search").val();
  
   if(!load_img) {  
       $("#loading").show();      
   }
  load_img = search.length === 0 ? false : true;
  
  if(search.length === 0){
     $("#loading").hide();
  }

  // Rest of your code goes here

  });
});
```

```css
#loading{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="search">
<div id="loading">
<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
  </div>
```

**However**, You should **reset** that flag `load_img` to **false** on `focusout or change or blue` of the **input** and when `length = 0` as well, so that **flag** can't bound to only `true` when it become **true** when the user type a keyword.

**RESET FLAG**

```
$("#search").on("change",function(){
    load_img = false;
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the help. Sorry but I'm still in the process of learning to use jQuery. May I know how to reset the load_img or if you have any reference for it.

Comment: Check answer again from start i updated the code that's all what you needed. I think i can get +1 for this Thanks

Comment: For the reset flag, do we insert it after the keyup function

Comment: For the updated answer, for keyup does not show the loading image but once I delete all the words, the image will appear.

Comment: wait i will create a demo for you!

Comment: @amran check the snippet !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120070/discussion-between-amran-and-m-tanzil).

Answer (score 1):

Use a global variable to set the state of the appended elements

```
var isTriggered = 0

$("#search").keyup(function(){
    if (isTriggered == 0) {
    isTriggered = 1;
    var search = $("#search").val();
    $("#loading").fadeIn(500);
    $.post('search_pr.php',
    {
        search : search
    })
    .done(function(data){
        $("#loading").fadeOut(500);
        $("#body").html(data);
    });  
}
});
```